# How to remove Antarctica from plotly world map?

Tags: python, plotly, data-science, plotly-python

I'm using [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) python library in order to make a choropleth. The data of choropleth (`choc_df`) has been handled by pandas. The choropleth is drawn by this code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=choc_df['ISO'],
    text=choc_df['company_location'],
    marker_line_color='black',
    marker_line_width=0.5,
    autocolorscale=False,
    colorscale='brbg_r',
    z=choc_df['rating'],
    customdata=choc_df['number'],
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "<b>%{text}</b>",
        "Number of brands: %{customdata}",
        "Rating: %{z}",
    ]) + '<extra></extra>',
), layout=dict(title='Rating',
        geo=dict(showcountries=True, countrycolor='#444444', showlakes=False)
))
```

I'm happy with the result: [image: resulting_choropleth]
The only thing that bothers me is the amount of space that Antartica takes for no reason :D. Is there a way to remove it from map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! Color Antarctica and it's border white (or whatever color your background is).

```
#using Plotly sample data
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                color="lifeExp", # lifeExp is a column of gapminder
                hover_name="country", # column to add to hover information
                color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)
```

Original

[image: Original]

"Hidden" Antarctica

```
fig.add_trace(go.Choropleth(locations=['ATA'],
            z=[0],
            colorscale=[[0,'white'], [1,'white']],
            marker_line_color='white',
            showlegend=False,
            showscale=False)
      )
```

[image: "Hidden" Antarctica]

Optional Zoom

```
fig.update_geos(lataxis_range=[-59, 90])
```

[image: Optional Zoom]

Answer (score 1):

You can [apparently](https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/#map-projections) set `lataxis_range=[-50,20]` and `lonaxis_range=[0, 200]` in the `geo` dict, so possibly setting `lataxis_range=[-90, 80]` might crop Antarctica out.

You can also try [automatic bounds](https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/#automatic-zooming-or-bounds-fitting) with `fitbounds="locations"` to see if that manages to crop out Antarctica too, since it has no data.

Comment: Second solution doesn't work, but the first is nice (but `lataxis_range` should be `[-59, 90]` and `lonaxis` shouldn't be set at all. The only problem is that it doesn't really change the map, it just zooms the map to a certain position, but it doesn't stop you from zooming out. Again, it's a nice solution, but I'm wondering if there could be some other way.